# ¿Cómo enviar objetos o listas a páginas?

Tags: angular

La idea es crear una lista y según el botón que se presione enviar un valor al formulario de otra página. Intento seguir un ejemplo que he encontrado pero no me funciona.

Este es el código que envía la información de la lista:

```
     catmenu = [];
      
      constructor(
        
    
        public servicio: ServiciosService,
        public route: ActivatedRoute,
        public router: Router,
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public ActivatedRouted:ActivatedRoute,
        
        
      ) { 
    
          this.catmenu = [
            {
              'title': 'Mascotas',
              'icon': 'angular',
              'color': '#E63135',
              
            },
            {
              'title': 'Plantas',
              'icon': 'css3',
              'color': '#0CA9EA'
            },
            {
              'title': 'Alimento',
              'icon': 'html5',
              'color': '#F46529'
            },
            {
              'title': 'Alimento vivo',
              'icon': 'javascript',
              'color': '#FFD439'
            },
            {
              'title': 'Accesorios mascotas',
              'icon': 'sass',
              'color': '#CE6296'
            },
            {
              'title': 'Accesorios plantas',
              'icon': 'nodejs',
              'color': '#78BD43'
            },
            {
              'title': 'servicios',
              'icon': 'python',
              'color': '#3575AC'
            },
            {
              'title': 'Adopciones',
              'icon': 'markdown',
              'color': '#412159'
            },
           
          ]
    
      }  
     
     
      
    
    
     openNavDetailsPage(item) {
  this.navCtrl.push(ProductoPage, { item: item });
}
```

en el html coloco esto :

```
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of catmenu" (click)="openNavDetailsPage(item)" icon-start>
      <ion-icon [name]="'logo-' + item.icon" [ngStyle]="{'color': item.color}" item-start></ion-icon>
      {{ item.title }}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

en el ts donde lo recibo tengo lo siguiente:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'navigation-details.html',
})
export class NavigationDetailsPage {
  item;

  constructor(params: NavParams) {
    this.item = params.data.item;
  }
```

y lo imprimo de la siguiente manera en el html:

```
<ion-title>
      {{ item.title }}
    </ion-title>
```

La función del ts openNavDetailsPage me sale marcada como si en la versión 5 de ionic esto no se pudiera utilizar de otra forma  para poder pasar la información del array.

En la función al poner el push me marca error:

```
openNavDetailsPage(item) { this.navCtrl.push(NavigationDetailsPage, { item: item }); }
Property 'push' does not exist on type 'NavController'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: perdona no entiendo a que te refieres

Comment: perdona en el html el *ngfor seria let item of catmenu

Comment: en la función al poner el push me marca error :         openNavDetailsPage(item) {
  this.navCtrl.push(NavigationDetailsPage, { item: item });
}

Comment: el error es este: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'NavController'.ts(2339)

Comment: mi funcion :    openNavDetailsPage(item) {
  this.navCtrl.push(ProductoPage, { item: item });
}